# Is is possible to delete Component HTML Content with JSF

Tags: javascript, jakarta-ee, jsf-2

hi i have HTML content like:

```
<div id="j_idt33:summary">
  <ul id="j_idt33:summary2" class="summary">
    <li style="margin-right: 85%; Color:red;">Some Error Message.</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

i want when the user click on a button to clear all the contents of that DIV to get output like:

```
<div id="j_idt33:summary">

</div>
```

is it possible to do something like that with JSF ?  or achieve that with JavaScript ? what do you suggest guys ?

please advise.

Comment: The functional requirement is not clear. Please clarify the functional requirement in detail and show JSF code instead of its generated HTML output. Particularly the mentioning of a HTML parser like Jsoup makes your question very confusing as it serves an entirely different purpose.

Comment: i am trying to workaround this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215720/faces-messages-are-not-cleared-on-subsequent-requests by clearing the div that hold the messages manually before adding new messages.

Comment: Note that the `div` and the nested `ul` have the same id (j_idt33:summary). This could create problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript side, you could do something like this:

```
document.getElementById("j_idt33:summary").innerHTML = "";
```

Or when you're using jQuery:

```
$("#j_idt33\\:summary").empty();
```

You only need to give the parent `NamingContainer` compnent which has a HTML representation with `id="j_idt33"` (I guess it's the `<h:form>`) a fixed ID so that the code is more robust. The generated ID may change with JSF impl/version and the component tree's state.